# Export multiple dataframe to different csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
ext = ('.tsv')
for files in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
  if files.endswith(ext):
    x = pd.read_table(files, sep='\t', usecols=['#Chrom','Pos','RawScore','PHRED'])
    x.drop_duplicates(subset ="Pos",keep = False, inplace = True)
    data_frame=x.head()
    print(data_frame)

       #Chrom        Pos  RawScore  PHRED
77171       6  167709702  7.852318   39.0
19180       6   31124849  7.623789   38.0
15823       6   29407955  6.982213   37.0
19182       6   31125257  6.817868   36.0
19974       6   31544591  6.201438   35.0
       #Chrom        Pos  RawScore  PHRED
52445       9  139634495  6.950686   36.0
46470       9  125391241  5.477094   34.0
49866       9  134385435  4.841222   33.0
48642       9  131475583  4.357986   31.0
40099       9  113233652  4.284035   31.0
       #Chrom        Pos  RawScore  PHRED
7050       13   32972626  6.472542   36.0
32416      13  100518634  5.405765   33.0
10834      13   42465713  4.406294   32.0
9963       13   39422624  4.374808   31.0
22993      13   76395620  4.193058   29.4
```

As you can imagine, I got multiple dataframes with the same columns names but from different Chromosomes.
How can I get this multiples dataframes in differents csv files?

Comment: _Which_ dataframes do you want in _what_ files? Please elaborate in the question.

Comment: At the end I want a csv file with all data of Chrm 9, and then another file with all data of Chrm 13... and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your dataFrames to .csv using panda's pandas.DataFrame.to_csv (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).
More specifically, in your case you can do this:

```
    for files in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if files.endswith(ext):
            x = pd.read_table(files, sep='\t', usecols= 
            ['#Chrom','Pos','RawScore','PHRED'])
            x.drop_duplicates(subset ="Pos",keep = False, inplace = True)
            x.to_csv(f'Chrom{x.iloc[0,0]}.csv')
```

In here, `x.iloc[0,0]` will take the first element of the first column which is the #Chrom. You can also do this manually. Note that this method would not work if you want to have two different DataFrames with the same #Chromosome. In that case, you have to manually input the name of the csv file.